# How to debug Square root overflow in VBA(Bug on MacOS v.16.36)

Tags: excel, vba, integer-overflow

I am a rookie of VBA that I have a problem to use sqr() in VBA.
Whenever I use Sqr() function in VBA, A message box appear" Run-time error'6' Overflow" on SigSqrdt = sigma * Sqr(dt) row.
And I am trying to simulate the Brownian Motion only.

```
Sub Simulating_Geometric_Brownian_Motion()
Dim T, S, mu, sigma, dt, SigSqrdt, LogS, drift, i, N
T = InputBox("Enter the length of the time period (T)")
N = InputBox("Enter the number of periods (N)")
S = InputBox("Enter the initial stock price (S)")
mu = InputBox("Enter the expected rate of return (mu)")
sigma = InputBox("Enter the volatility (sigma)")
dt = T / N
SigSqrdt = sigma * Sqr(dt)
drift = (mu - 0.5 * sigma * sigma) * dt
LogS = Log(S)
ActiveCell.Value = "Time"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "stock price"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = 0  ' beginning time
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = S 'beginning stock price
For i = 1 To N
ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 0) = i * dt
LogS = LogS + SigSqrdt * RandN()
ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 1) = Exp(LogS)
Next i
End Sub

Function RandN()
RandN = Application.NormSInv(Rnd())
End Function
```

Sample inputs:

```
T=1000, N=1000, S=10, mu=10, sigma=1
```

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: In `SigSqrdt = sigma * Sqr(dt)` the overflow is likely to be the `*` rather than `Sqr(dt)`. Also, why not declare the types of the variables?

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I give it reasonable inputs. Others really can't help you unless you give enough information for them to reproduce the problem. Please answer the question that @BigBen asked.

Comment: What input you use?

Comment: Indent your code. Add `Option Explicit`, and declare your variables. If you declare `Dim SigSrdt As Double` it will hold a fairly large value but it could still overflow when using very large numbers. NOTE: The largest number a double can hold is 1.79769313486231570 • 10^308

Comment: Without providing the inputs you are using, this question is likely to be closed as "needing details to debug."

Comment: I just put, T=1000, N=1000, S=10, mu=10, sigma=1, nothing special

Comment: How did you declare the variables? `Dim T, S, mu, sigma, dt, SigSqrdt, LogS, drift, i, N A Double` only declares `N` as double.

Comment: Cuz I don't think the input is the point, that I tried every combination of reasonable input

Comment: That code with those inputs does not lead to the bug that you are reporting. Something else is happening here, something which likely involves code that you haven't shown. Please read about the importance of having a [mcve].

Comment: I run these VBA codes on macOS version, Is there any difference?

Comment: Unlikely to be what makes a difference. As a simple test, create a brand-new workbook and paste the code that you posted here, and no other code, into that new workbook. Run it in that new workbook with the inputs that you gave. Does it still have the same bug?

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint and step through the code in the debugger, looking at the values of the variables in the locals window. Google "Debugging VBA" if you need some tips about using the debugging tools.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215514/excel-vba-overflow-error-when-it-shouldnt/45215661#45215661 Perhaps `SigSqrdt = cDbl(sigma) * Sqr(dt)`

Comment: Well, I've tried tmy code on Windows Excel 2013 , it works. So probably there are bugs on MacOS.

Comment: I also tried macOS Excel v.16.34, which is fine. But for macOS Excel v.16.36, the Overflow Error on the function sqr() always happen.